# Replacing PDImageXObject with another PDFBOX 2.0.3

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I've read all similar questions and answers and I'm still stuck beacuse old questions were for old versions.

I want to replace all images in given PDF with external images.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
   for(int a=0;a<doc.getNumberOfPages().size();a++){
        PDPage p = doc.getPage(a);
        PDResources resources = p.getResources();
        for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
            if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject original_img = ((PDImageXObject) xObject);
                PDImageXObject replacement_img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(f.getImages().get(a), doc);
            }        
        }
    }
```

So, I have 2 PDImageXObjects names original_img and replacement_img. Replacement_img has to overwrite original_img.

Comment: Have you tried to *replace* yet, i.e. something like `resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img)` after instantiating `replacement_img`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. It works. Thank you @mkl

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *replace* the old image by the new image, one has to set the resource in question to the new image, i.e.

```
resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
```

after the instantiation of `replacement_img` in the OP's code.